# Where can I find RPC_User and RPC_Password for my Python Script?

Tags: json-rpc, connection, hosting

I'm still struggling with this to obtain "rpc_user" and "rpc_password" this is the Python Script

[image]

I did try others to fill in others network like Blockdaemon.com but it does not work, which is why I take off and leave it empty then I get the same error as per the snapshot below:

[image]

I have tried to find LocalHost to support this but it doesn't work even though via CMD and Ubuntu.

Any recommendation? Sorry again to inform I'm no expert in this as I'm a nerd who is still figuring out the way to solve this.  My GOAL is to able to Connect to any LocalHost for me to Post my Bitcoin Transaction.

Appreciate your guidance on this. Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have a bitcoin node that are running on your computer?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo - Nope I don't have except for the Bitcoin Core V0.20.0

Answer (score 1):

To use this library you need an instance of [Bitcoin core](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin)!

If you start with Bitcoin I suggest you to run an instance of bitcoin core and understand how the config it. You can find a good start [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node)!

In addition, to use the lib inside your question you can following the steps below:

1. Download Bitcoin core and run an instance of it, I suggest you to run Bitcoin core on testnet, because it is not a small instance of "real" bitcoin network
2. Config Bitcoin core with a conf that accepts the connection on RPC!
3. With the RPC username and RPC password, use your code to connect to the Bitcoin code RPC interface.

Good hacking!